# Moving HTML controls from one page to other

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, d3.js, svg

I am working on a project which has 4 tabbed view (separate HTML pages).Each of these views have bunch of SVG charts implemented using d3.js .Now the client wants a feature where he could cut&paste / move charts from one tabbed view to another.What is the best way to achieve this? I have already used interact.min.js for resizing & dragging/moving charts within the page limits.

This project is in a offline format i.e. There is no usage of any server side language.All your suggestions should take into this consideration.Currently all the views are launched by clicking html page from a folder present in local file system.

Comment: I don't think those tools would have any sort of functionality like that. What you'd need to do is probably create an "export control" button which would serialize the control and store it in a browser or session cookie, then create an "import control" button that would gather that cookie info and drop it at the bottom of your control list on the new page where it can be dragged into position normally.

Comment: @Forklift think interactivity is key for client but still using export/import logic in background can help me in getting there !!!

Comment: you could consider adding a right-click context to each control that includes "send to page 1, send to page 2, etc" which will trigger the export, redirect, and import actions automatically and all the client will need to do from there is just drag to preferred spot. Or right click -> export, which brings up a wizard that selects what page and whether top or bottom.

Comment: @Forklift worthy solution to move in some direction !!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I Think This might will Help You . You can Replace Whole HTML1 With HTML2  Tab and vice verse .

**HTML**

```
<div id="div1"> HULK </div>

<div id="div2">THOR </div>

<input class="button" type="button" value="Replace THOR with HULK">
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(".button").click(function(){
$('#div2').replaceWith($('#div1').html());
})
```

This is just an Idea which help you i think.

[JS Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cy1hnmvv/)

Comment: The problem is that the divs to be moved are potentially on different pages, so your solution is not going to work at all. This would only work on objects that exist in the DOM, which they would not for a page the user is not on.

Comment: i just gave the idea , same concept will use for page , you have to save that HTML temporary somewhere else. like you said.

Comment: @AmiteshKumar .it would be diificult to apply when crossing boundaries of page and we cannot even pre assume what will be target place of landing for a chart that is being moved !! BTW welcome your suggestion !!